# Tradução para 'Walk away from the ashes'

Tags: expressões, tradução, tradução-inglês, figuras-de-linguagem

Em SEWorking, encontrei uma expressão interessante em uma [resposta](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/113518/how-can-i-make-a-company-i-co-founded-a-better-place-to-be-or-cleanly-move-onto/113528#113528). No final está escrito:

> This sounds like a bridge that was burned by your abusive partner, not
>   you. ***Walk away from the ashes.***
>
> > Isso me soa uma ponte que foi queimada por seu parceiro abusivo, não você. ***Vá embora das cinzas***.

Essa seria a tradução literal, porém gostaria de algo equivalente, uma que tivesse o mesmo sentido original em inglês de se abster de uma situação comprometida e a mesma *imagery* também. '**Walk away from the ashes**' realmente invoca uma imagem impactante na mente. Sugestões?

Comment: Antes que perguntem: almejo tradução de *Walk away from the ashes*, não de qualquer outra coisa.

Comment: walk away é afastarse de algo ou sair de uma situação. O verbo se usa muito no sentido figurativo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu tinha lido esse post mais cedo e a expressão é mesmo impactante mas note que ela é um complemento de *a bridge that was burned* que em português poderia ser traduzido não literalmente como: Uma porta (oportunidade) se fechou (p/ sempre).

Por isso fica difícil de traduzir e qualquer tentativa deve levar em conta todo o contexto.

Minhas propostas são:

*This sounds like a bridge that was burned by your abusive partner, not you. Walk away from the ashes.*

Parece que uma ponte foi queimada (atrás de você) por seu sócio abusivo, não você. Se afaste das cinzas.

Parece que uma porta se fechou por culpa de seu sócio (que maltratou você), não sua. Afaste-se disso e procure trilhar outro caminho.

Parece que seu irascível sócio destruiu/demoliu qq futuro que havia entre vcs, isso foi culpa dele não sua. Afaste-se dos escombros.

Seu sócio pisou na bola com vc e destruiu qq (sonho para o?) futuro que vcs tinham. Sacuda a poeira e dê a volta por cima.

Comment: Esse é mesmo um ponto relevante. É importante primeiro traduzir adequadamente a primeira frase (e *to burn bridges* de fato é bem traduzido por algo como "fechar portas" nesse caso).

Comment: Concordo completamente: "ashes/cinzas" faz sentido porque antes se falou em "ponte queimada". "Se afaste" também foi logo o que me ocorreu para "walk away". Em vez de "cinzas" poderiam também ser "se afaste dos escombros" ou "dos destroços".

Answer (score 1):

Algumas possibilidades são:

- Deixe as cinzas para trás.
- Não se prenda às cinzas.
- Abandone as cinzas.
- Dê as costas às cinzas.

Comment: Validei a outra resposta porém aprecio esta pela maior gama de alternativas que usam explicitamente o termo figurado '*cinzas*'